# Android Studio crashing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Project My Application11 is using the following JDK location when running Gradle:
C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio1/jre
Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to
spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal
while using Android Studio.
More info...

After showing this error automatically closed without showing any error.

1. tried jdk 8 and 13 also java working in cmd
2. Reinstall android studio
3. OS windows 10 from official site

Answer (score 0):

You may need to select **Gradle JDK: Embedded JDK** in the: *Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle*.

[image: screenshot]